# lxml get second last element

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have a bunch of `ul` and I want to get the second last `li` element in each. The number of list items is variable so I cannot do something like

```
tree.xpath('//ul/li[3]') # if it had four elements
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`last()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-last):

```
tree.xpath('//ul/li[last()-1]')
```

According to the documentation:

> ```
> fn:last() as xs:integer
> ```
>
> Summary: Returns the context size from the dynamic context. (See Section C.2 Dynamic Context ComponentsXP.) If the context item is undefined, an error is raised: [err:XPDY0002]XP.